# How to extract data between tr tags?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, html

I have CMS website, maked in Joomla. There are articles about traveling and I've dates in there. Dates are in tables on each page. Question is how to extract dates like array from table inherit in article and copy them in dropdown box in contact form? This is example,

```
<tr> 
  <td>08.03.2012.</td> 
  <td>22.03.2012.</td>
</tr>
```

How to extract those dates and put in dropdown box in contact form?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assign a `name` to the `<td>`'s (same name for all):

```
<tr> 
  <td name="NAME_YOUVE_CREATED">08.03.2012.</td> 
  <td name="NAME_YOUVE_CREATED">22.03.2012.</td>
</tr>
```

Declare a drop-down without any `option` items, with an `ID` (let's say "date_dropdown"):

```
<tr>
    <select id="date_dropdown">
    </select>
</tr>
```

Then use jQuery to get the value and place it in the dropdown:

```
$('td[name="NAME_YOUVE_CREATED"]').each(function() {
    //Obtain date value from <td>
    var dateToExtract = $(this).text();

    //Place value in dropdown
    $('select#date_dropdown').after('<option value="' + dateToExtract  + '"> ' + dateToExtract + ' </option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the DOM ([Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)) like this:

```
$test = "<tr> 
  <td>08.03.2012.</td> 
  <td>22.03.2012.</td>
</tr>";

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($test);

$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

echo '<select name="date">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$items->item($i)->nodeValue.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Please note that this is a basic example without knowing details of what you want to do. The above code will output the following HTML for you:

```
<select name="date"><option value="0">08.03.2012.</option><option value="1">22.03.2012.</option></select>
```